# Email etiquette; Whether to reply to an email when delivered information I requested

Tags: communication, email-etiquette

Maybe a minuscule thing to worry about, but I am still curious.

When people (especially outside of my company) respond to me with the information I requested, I send them a reply thanking them for their help/support or maybe their fast reply.

As a socially awkward person, I would like to know how you feel about this sort of correspondence.

Comment: @mustaccio It does in a way, yes. I had checked if this was asked before... Apologies for the redundancy, and my thanks to everyone who gave feedback below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are being polite, it costs nothing and is very unlikely to annoy anyone.

As the sender of the information, it is helpful to know that you've received it and that I don't need to check up.

Answer (score 5):

It is nice to receive thanks or confirmation of the data getting there and its suitability.

Not having any feedback always leaves the nagging question 'did it get there or was it lost"?

So, if someone always gives a simple "Thank you" as a reply, then if something goes missing people notice.

Answer (score 1):

If someone took the time and effort to provide you with something that you need it is always appropriate to express gratitude, immediately, with a "thank you".

In addition to that, it's also good to follow-up, perhaps in a subsequent discussion with how you were able to use the information they provided you. Everyone likes to help others and being appreciated for that, even when it's something small, feels good to most people. Moreover, if (as you say) you're socially awkward, it gives you something to talk about.

Finally, it's good practice to give credit to the person publicly. If you were able to complete something with some help from them be sure to name them so that others know they were helpful. Give credit where credit is due. Even if you didn't directly use their contribution, it was an effort by them and even evaluating (and rejecting it) warrants some appreciation because it was part of the path you took in your own work.

Answer (score 0):

> When people (especially outside of my company) respond to me with the
> information I requested, I send them a reply thanking them for their
> help/support or maybe their fast reply.

Seems reasonable. Don't be too verbose in your reply. Don't overthink it.

Comment: In this case I prefer to usually overthink it. There's nothing worse than a canned thank you answer for something bigger. I accept it for small pieces of information, but absolutely hate this when it's some special effort and the answer isn't personalized. I instantly dislike such people as not worth my time next time.